# Instantiation of anonymous abstract class raises error in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I have the following method in MainActivity taken from (https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/text-recognition-for-android-using-google-mobile-vision-a8ffabe3f5d6):

```
private void startCameraSource() {

    ...

    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies not loaded yet");
    } else {

        ...

        //Set the TextRecognizer's Processor.
        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            /**
             * Detect all the text from camera using TextBlock and the values into a stringBuilder
             * which will then be set to the textView.
             * */
            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> detections) {
                ...

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the error: `error: <anonymous com.example.myqrcodescanner.MainActivity$5> is not abstract and does not override abstract method receiveDetections(Detections<TextBlock>) in Processor`
 and the error points to the line: `textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock>() {`

Any ideas?

Comment: "Is not abstract and does not override abstract method receiveDetections(Detections<TextBlock>)" => override that method and you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain this? `'receiveDetections(Detections<TextBlock>)' in 'Anonymous class derived from com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector.Processor' clashes with 'receiveDetections(Detections<T>)' in 'com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector.Processor'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`?

Comment: same 'erasure'? what is that supposed to mean? you mean signature? no, they don't have the same signature. the one's a generic, the other's a specific class named TextBlock

Comment: `erasure` is the term in the error message. Read the documentation.

Comment: so why don't you show that error message? Either way, the result remains the same (for the error message you did show). Either you implement that method, or declare your class to be abstract.